# Advice on installing bar top on half wall

Tags: woodworking, kitchen-counters, countertops

I am preparing to attach a piece of butcher clock (about 42" L x 18" W) to the top of a half wall that w recently built partially across the entryway to our kitchen. I'm trying to figure out the best way to securely attach the butcher block to the top of the wall, which is only about 5" wide. Attached a pic of the bar top being held in place.[image]

From my research so far, it seems like my options are either corbels or steel brackets, and drilling up into the butcher block through the brackets or corbels. I was planning to use construction adhesive to secure the board to the top of the wall, but from what I've read glue is not recommended to allow the board to expand and contract (otherwise can split/crack).

Any advice on whether the brackets/corbels will be enough, or if something else is needed to make sure the cbar top is secure? ('m sure ideally attaching the butcher block before finishing the half wall is ideal to secure it from the bottom - though at the same time wouldn't be able to mount the brackets). Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

From your post, it's not clear whether the supporting wall is finished or not. That would be the ideal way to *start* securing it - by screwing up from the bottom. However, consider that your model will normally have her elbows resting *on* the bar, not under it, and that she's probably not the biggest guest who will ever belly up. Just a few screws from the bottom may not be sufficient to support the weight of Junior, the Utes' nose guard, when he comes to lean on it.

Really, you'll want some sort of brackets, attached to the bottom of the counter, then into *studs* in the half wall to securely attach this and support the weight of people leaning on it. You *can* cantilever a counter top like this, but it would need a much wider attachment area to counteract the weight of people leaning on the unsupported side.

---

Do be aware that generally it's frowned upon to make this type of permanent alteration to a rental. Of course, I'm making that assumption based on the Utes decoration on the wall, and it's entirely possible you're just a fan and that you own the place.

Also, [that's not butcher block](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/12778/polyurethane-over-boiled-linseed-oil-timing-butcher-block-tabletop#comment26436_12778). But that's just a nit-pick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Agree about needing to support people leaning on it (we are actually just holding it up in place in the photo to show what it will look like). Planning to use some heavy-duty shelving brackets below, probably three of them, that claim to hold 300 lbs (attached to studs). The other option I was considering was attaching legs to the corners and connecting to the ground - obviously would be good support but a pain to navigate. And it is our house ha - the Utes decor is just covering up a hole in the wall where we started exposing the brick ;)

Comment: Yeah, I figured she was your temporary support. ;) Legs would be good but you'd be stubbing your toe on them. Just make sure you attach the shelf supports to studs and you should be good to go!

Comment: Also, spend a moment to take the [tour] to see the proper way to say "thanks" 'round here. ;)

Comment: Appreciate the advice - and to clarify for anyone else, the wall is indeed finished already, otherwise would definitely screw up into the block there as well (am considering cutting a hole in the drywall to do that still but don't know if it's necessary).